# Obj-C - All Custom MKMapView annotations not always showing on MapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to display multiple arrays of locations on my mapView with the below code (Restaurants, Parks, Meet Ups & Stores). When I open the app, not all addresses inside the arrays are displayed on my mapView (even though all data is returned) - e.g. sometimes only 'Stores' and 'Parks' arrays of annotations will show up on my map, but Restaurants aren't visible (even though data for all arrays is returned successfully). If I close out and reopen the app, sometimes Parks will show on the map, but nothing else. Any idea why this happens, and how I can fix it? Code updated below. Been at this forever!

**Note: ParksAnnotation, RestAnnotation, meetupAnn, & StoreAnnotation are all MKPointAnnotation classes.**

**UPDATE (10/13/2020):** I tried logging 'placemarks' under the block of code that retrieves and geocodes my 'Stores' coordinates. It appears as though self.storeData is populated, as is the created NSDictionary storeFields. That said, when I log 'placemarks', it isn't returning any coordinates, even though storeFields[@"address"] is populated. The other blocks of code seem to be doing their job just fine (ie. retrieving Meet Ups and retrieving Parks). So Meet Ups, Restaurants and Parks annotations appear fine, but all Stores annotations aren't populated. This happens to at least one type of annotation (sometimes it's Stores that's missing, other times it's Parks) at random when I launch the app. I can't for the life of me sort out why this is happening.

**See below code:**

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "StoreAnnotation.h"
#import "ParksAnnotation.h"
#import "RestAnnotation.h"
#import "meetupAnn.h"


@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController


      -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            

               NSMutableDictionary *viewParamsallUsers1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
               [viewParamsallUsers1 setValue:@"hosted_meet_ups" forKey:@"view_name"];
               [DIOSView viewGet:viewParamsallUsers1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                   
                   self.meetUps = [responseObject mutableCopy];
                  
                   int index = 0;
                   
                   
                   for (NSMutableDictionary *allMeetups in self.meetUps) {
                       
                       NSString *location = allMeetups[@"where"];
                       NSString *userNames = allMeetups[@"node_title"];
                       NSString *userBio = allMeetups[@"body"];
                    
      
                       self.alertMessage = [allMeetups[@"node_title"] mutableCopy];
                       
                  
                       CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                       [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
                                          completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                              if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                                  CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                                  MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                                                  
                                                  MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                                                  
                                                  region.span.longitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                                  region.span.latitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                                  
                                                  
                                                  meetupAnn *meet = [[meetupAnn alloc] init];
                                                  meet.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                                                  meet.title = userNames;
                                                  meet.subtitle = userBio;
                                                  meet.index = index;  // Store index here.
                                                  
                                                  [self.mapView addAnnotation:meet];
                                              }
                                          }
                        ];
                       
                       index = index + 1;
        
                   }
                
               
                   
               } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
               }];
           
        
            
        
            
            /// GRAB ALL RESTAURANT LOCATIONS ///
            
            NSMutableDictionary *viewParams6 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [viewParams6 setValue:@"restaurants" forKey:@"view_name"];
            [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams6 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                
                self.neighbourhoodData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
              
                int index = 0;
                
                
                for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocationsFriend in self.neighbourhoodData) {
                    
                
                    NSString *location = multiplelocationsFriend[@"address"];
                    NSString *userNames = multiplelocationsFriend[@"node_title"];
                     NSString *ampRemoved = [userNames stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
                    
                    NSString *userBio = multiplelocationsFriend[@"body"];
                    self.x3 = multiplelocationsFriend[@"x3"];
             
                    
                    CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                    [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
                                       completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                           if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                               CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                               MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                                               
                                               MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                                               
                                               region.span.longitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                               region.span.latitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                               
                                               
                                               RestAnnotation *point1 = [[RestAnnotation alloc] init];
                                               point1.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                                               point1.title = ampRemoved;
                                               point1.subtitle = userBio;
                                              
                                               point1.index = index;  // Store index here.
                                              
                                               
                                               [self.mapView addAnnotation:point1];
                                           }
                                       }
                     ];
                    
                    index = index + 1;
              
                }
         
                
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];
            
            
        
            
            NSString *test = self.areaName;
            NSLog(@"SHOW TEST %@", test);
            
            
              /// GRAB ALL STORE LOCATIONS ///
               
               NSMutableDictionary *viewParams7 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
               [viewParams7 setValue:@"stores" forKey:@"view_name"];
               [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams7 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                   
                   self.storesData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
                 
                   int index = 0;
                   
                   
                   for (NSMutableDictionary *storeFields in self.storesData) {
                       
                    
                       NSString *location = storeFields[@"address"];
                       NSString *userNames = storeFields[@"node_title"];
                        NSString *ampRemoved = [userNames stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
                       
                       NSString *userBio = storeFields[@"body"];
                       self.x3 = storeFields[@"x3"];
                
                       
                       CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                       [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
                                          completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                              if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                                  CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                                  MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                                                  
                                                  MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                                                  
                                                  region.span.longitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                                  region.span.latitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                                  
                                                  
                                                  StoreAnnotation *point2 = [[StoreAnnotation alloc] init];
                                                  point2.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                                                  point2.title = ampRemoved;
                                                  point2.subtitle = userBio;
                                                 
                                                  point2.index = index;  // Store index here.
                                                 
                                                  
                                                  [self.mapView addAnnotation:point2];
                                                  
                                               
                                                  
                                              }
                                          }
                        ];
                       
                       index = index + 1;
             
                   }
            
                   
               } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
               }];
               
               
            
                    /// GRAB ALL PARKS LOCATIONS ///
                         
                         NSMutableDictionary *viewParams8 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
                         [viewParams8 setValue:@"parks" forKey:@"view_name"];
                         [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams8 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                             
                             self.parksData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
                          
                             
                             int index = 0;
                             
                             
                             for (NSMutableDictionary *parkFields in self.parksData) {
                                 
                                 //  NSLog(@"WHAT IS IN FRIENDS %@", self.friendData);
                                 
                                 NSString *location = parkFields[@"address"];
                                 NSString *userNames = parkFields[@"node_title"];
                                  NSString *ampRemoved = [userNames stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
                                 
                                 NSString *userBio = parkFields[@"body"];
                                 self.x3 = parkFields[@"x3"];
                          
                                 
                                 CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                                 [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                                        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                                            CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                                            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                                                            
                                                            MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                                                            
                                                            region.span.longitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                                            region.span.latitudeDelta /= 150.0;
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            ParksAnnotation *point3 = [[ParksAnnotation alloc] init];
                                                            point3.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                                                            point3.title = ampRemoved;
                                                            point3.subtitle = userBio;
                                                           
                                                            point3.index = index;  // Store index here.
                                                           
                                                            
                                                            [self.mapView addAnnotation:point3];
                                                            
                                                            
                                                         
                                                           
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                  ];
                                 
                                 index = index + 1;
                              
        
                             }
                       
                            
                         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                         }];
                    
            }
        
          - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
    {
    
       static dispatch_once_t onceToken; dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        
       MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
        mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
        mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.5;
        mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.5;
        
        [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
        
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager = nil;
    
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 8000, 8000);
           [mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
            
           [mapView addAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];
    
            
           });
    }
    
        - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
           
         
            if([annotation isKindOfClass:[StoreAnnotation class]]) {
                static NSString *identifier = @"stores";
                MKAnnotationView *storesView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
                
                if(storesView == nil) {
                    
                   
                   storesView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
                    storesView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
                  
                   storesView.canShowCallout = YES;
                    storesView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"storeann4.png"];
                    
                  
                }
                
               else  {
                    
                   storesView.annotation = annotation;
                
          
            }
              
                return storesView;
               
            }
            
            if([annotation isKindOfClass:[meetupAnn class]]) {
                static NSString *identifier = @"meetUps";
                MKAnnotationView *pulsingView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
                
                if(pulsingView == nil) {
                    
                    pulsingView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
                    pulsingView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
                    pulsingView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meetupbeacon.png"];
                    pulsingView.canShowCallout = YES;
               
               }
                
                else  {
                
                 pulsingView.annotation = annotation;
             
            }
              
                return pulsingView;
               
            }
                
                if([annotation isKindOfClass:[ParksAnnotation class]]) {
                    static NSString *identifier = @"parks";
                    MKAnnotationView *parksView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
                    
                    if(parksView == nil) {
                        
                      
                       parksView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
                        parksView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
                       parksView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"parksann.png"];
                        parksView.canShowCallout = YES;
                   
                    }
                    
                   else  {
                        
                        
                        parksView.annotation = annotation;
               
                }
                  
                    return parksView;
                   
                }
            
                if([annotation isKindOfClass:[RestAnnotation class]]) {
                    static NSString *identifier = @"rests";
                    MKAnnotationView *restView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
                    
                    if(restView == nil) {
            
                       restView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
                        restView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
                       restView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"restann.png"];
                       restView.canShowCallout = YES;
                   
                    }
                    
                else  {
                        
                        
                        restView.annotation = annotation;
                   
                }
                  
                    return restView;
                   
                }
```

Comment: Perhaps `viewDidLoad` is too early?

Comment: @matt What's the alternative? viewDidAppear?

Comment: I don’t know, try it.

Comment: Tried it - no change / didn't make a difference. But thanks. @matt

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is some of them might be offscreen or overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if some of your geocoding requests are failing inconsistently.
`CLGeocoder` rate limits your requests and if you do too many requests in a short time, you'll receive an error. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423509-geocodeaddressstring?language=objc

Check if you are getting any reason for failure inside `NSError* error` inside the completionHandler block.

As many times as it fails, you should see as many less number of annotations on the MapView because it is not entering the following code path.

```
if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
    // Not entering here
}

if (nil != error) {
    // Could land here
}
```

The only other reason would be not properly calculating map region to show all annotations in screen. Make sure you are calculating/adjusting the region correctly upon each annotation being added to the mapView.

```
  // Define these variables globally in the view controller
  CLLocationDegrees minLatitude = 90.0;
  CLLocationDegrees maxLatitude = -90.0;
  CLLocationDegrees minLongitude = 180.0;
  CLLocationDegrees maxLongitude = -180.0;
  

 // Call following method every time a new annotation needs to be added to the mapView
 -(void)addAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation toMapView:(MKMapView*)mapView {
      // Add the annotation to map
      [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
       
      // Set the map region to make it visible along with all other annotations
      CLLocationDegrees latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude;
      CLLocationDegrees longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude;
      
      minLatitude = min(minLatitude, latitude);
      maxLatitude = max(maxLatitude, latitude);
      minLongitude = min(minLongitude, longitude);
      maxLongitude = max(maxLongitude, longitude);

      CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = (maxLatitude - minLatitude);
      CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = (maxLongitude - minLongitude);
      
      CLLocationDegrees midLatitude = (maxLatitude - latitudeDelta/2);
      CLLocationDegrees midLongitude = (maxLongitude - longitudeDelta/2);
      CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(midLatitude, midLongitude);

      MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
      MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
      
      if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(center)) {
          [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
      }
 }
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Testing your answer now by having my backend do the geocoding. Will let you know how it goes shortly. I was wondering if this might be the case, but there are tons of apps that pull hundreds (or thousands) of geocoded locations onto a mapview.

Comment: Wow, you nailed this. This was absolutely the problem. Thank you SO much. I was able to fix this by having my database do the geocoding instead of having the app do it. Now my app is just pulling the finished coordinates from my database into an array. You. Rock.

Answer (score 1):

As Ramis said, the problem is that you're setting the `displayPriority` before you even instantiate the `pulsingView`. Thus, the `MKAnnotationView` you subsequently instantiate never got its `displayPriority` set.

That having been said, I'd suggest a slightly different implementation, though. Specifically, I'd move the configuration of the annotation view into its own subclass, rather than cluttering the view controller with this sort of code:

```
@interface MeetUpAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView
@end

@implementation MeetUpAnnotationView

- (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
        self.canShowCallout = YES;
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meetupbeacon.png"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    [super setAnnotation:annotation];
    self.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
}

@end
```

Then, if targeting iOS 11 or later, your view controller's `viewDidLoad` should register that subclass.

Now, if this is the only annotation view that you’re showing in iOS 11, you don't need a `viewForAnnotation` at all and can just register your default annotation view:

```
[self.mapView registerClass:[MeetUpAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
```

And having registered the annotation view class, you're done. No `viewForAnnotation` is needed or desired.

---

The only time you have to implement `viewForAnnotation` in iOS 11 and later is if you have multiple custom annotation view types on your map. In that case, you'd register them:

```
[self.mapView registerClass:[MeetUpAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:meetupIdentifier];
[self.mapView registerClass:[SomeOtherAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:someOtherIdentifier];
```

And then use `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:forAnnotation:` in your `viewForAnnotation`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MeetupAnn class]]) {
        return [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:meetupIdentifier forAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SomeOtherAnnotation class]]) {
        return [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:someOtherIdentifier forAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    ...

    return nil;
}
```

---

As you can see, in iOS 11 (especially when you have only one annotation view type), the code is greatly simplified.

But if you need to support older iOS versions, you can't register the identifier and you have to use the older `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:`, but I'd still let the annotation view subclass take care of configuring itself. But, a more subtle problem in your code is that you are not setting the `annotation` in an `else` clause, so make sure to do that, e.g.:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MeetupAnn class]]) {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:meetupIdentifier];
        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[MeetUpAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:meetupIdentifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I've implemented the above, and granted, it works far better than what I'd had. That said, there are still some times where I launch, and my 'Meet Up' locations do not show up on the map :(

Comment: Annotations are a fairly bullet-proof sort of thing, that we all use all the time. So maybe your coordinates are not right. Maybe the map view outlet isn't hooked up right. It could be tons of things, but I'd wager that it is not related to this annotation view subclass and associated code. It's undoubtedly something else going on. We'd need [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: One thing I can think of: in my code above, when I'm adding meetupAnn to self.friendsMapView, this line: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *neighbourmapView; meetupAnn is an MKAnnotationView. That said, that line throws me a warning: Sending 'meetupAnn *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation> _Nonnull'. I assume this is because meetupAnn is an MKAnnotationView, and not an MKAnnotationPoint? Any idea how I should/can alter this line to fix the warning, and see if it's the cause of my problems? Thanks Rob!

Comment: The objects you add via `addAnnotation` must be annotations (e.g. `MKPointAnnotation` or some subclass or other `MKAnnotation` conforming class), _not_ annotation views. Above, I assumed `MeetupAnn` (whose capitalization I changed, as class names always start with uppercase letter) was an annotation, not an annotation view, as it makes no sense to pass an annotation _view_ to `addAnnotations`. Annotations are model objects that represent some geographic location/name. Annotation views are the view which will be rendered on screen. Don’t conflate the two, as they’re completely different.

Comment: Just added some edits to my code. I realized that the reason the annotations dont all always show up is because my data is retrieved too late; even in my console, it's the last thing to be returned...just not sure how to fix this :/

Comment: @Brittany the timing doesn’t matter, because if you add the annotations to the map view (and have `displayPriority` of “required”) they will appear on the map. Are you calling `addAnnotations` after you finish fetching them?

Comment: I have displayPriority in (this doesn't seem to do much tbh), and I'm calling addAnnotation after retrieving both sets of data...so I'm not quite sure why it's acting the way it is. I feel like I've tried everything. And in my console, all data is being returned, which makes the lack of annotations even more of a head scratcher. Going to keep at it today - will let you know what I find!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired to empty object. Try to assign display priority in two case:

1. When pulsingView is not nil.
2. After pulsingView allocated.

   ```
   if([annotation isKindOfClass:[meetupAnn class]]) {
        static NSString *identifier = @"currentLocation";
        MKAnnotationView *pulsingView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self.friendsMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if(pulsingView == nil) {
            pulsingView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            pulsingView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
            pulsingView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pulsingView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meetupbeacon.png"];
            NSLog(@"Location Returned");
        } else {
            pulsingView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
            // TODO: Do map pin initial setup.
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: @Rob Thanks for refreshing objective-c memory. I did update my answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem. But you still have a problem that if an annotation view is reused (i.e. `pulsingView` was not `nil`), that you never reset its `annotation` property. In the `else` clause, add a `pulsingView.annotation = annotation`.